# Ubuntu sound problems

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I bought myself a Huawei Matebook 14s laptop and installed Ubuntu 22.04 on it. 
This laptop has two pairs of speakers. 
The problem is that the system defines the first as speakers
and the second as headphones. 
How do I get them to work together? 
Maybe I need to install additional drivers or something similar,
a sound card like from Intel.

I tried restarting PulseAudio, but it didn't help.

Comment: `a sound card like from intel` Not sure how adding yet another sound card would fix Ubuntu being unable to recognise the existing audio correctly. `I tried restarting pulseaudio` did you make any configuration changes before restarting it?

Comment: No, I didn't make any changes, the only thing I did after installation was to update all the drivers, mainly so that the video card would work normally

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, and based on the materials I found, I wrote a daemon that solves it. You can get it in my GitHub repo: https://github.com/Smoren/huawei-ubuntu-sound-fix.

### Problem

The headphone and speaker channels are mixed up in the sound card driver for Linux distributions.

When headphones are connected, the system considers that sound should be output from the speakers. When the headphones are off, the system tries to output sound through them.

#### Problem details (found [here](https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/3350#issuecomment-1301070327))

Looks like there is some weird hardware design, because from my prospective, the interesting widgets are:

- 0x01 - Audio Function Group
- 0x10 - Headphones DAC (really both devices connected here)
- 0x11 - Speaker DAC
- 0x16 - Headphones Jack
- 0x17 - Internal Speaker

And:

- widgets 0x16 and 0x17 simply should be connected to different DACs 0x10 and 0x11,
  but Internal Speaker 0x17 ignores the connection select command
  and uses the value from Headphones Jack 0x16.
- Headphone Jack 0x16 is controlled with some weird stuff,
  so it should be enabled with GPIO commands for Audio Group 0x01.
- Internal Speaker 0x17 is coupled with Headphone Jack 0x16,
  so it should be explicitly disabled with EAPD/BTL Enable command.

### Solution

A daemon has been implemented that monitors the connection/disconnection of headphones and accesses the sound card device in order to switch playback to the right place.

#### huawei-soundcard-headphones-monitor.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# ensures script can run only once at a time
pidof -o %PPID -x $0 >/dev/null && echo "Script $0 already running" && exit 1

function move_output() {
   hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x16 0x701 "$@" > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
}

function move_output_to_speaker() {
    move_output 0x0001
}

function move_output_to_headphones() {
    move_output 0x0000
}

function switch_to_speaker() {
    move_output_to_speaker

    # enable speaker
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x17 0x70C 0x0002 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    # disable headphones
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x1 0x715 0x2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
}

function switch_to_headphones() {
    move_output_to_headphones

    # disable speaker
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x17 0x70C 0x0000 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    # pin output mode
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x1 0x717 0x2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    # pin enable
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x1 0x716 0x2 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    # clear pin value
    hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x1 0x715 0x0 > /dev/null 2> /dev/null

    # sets amixer sink port to headphones instead of the speaker
    pacmd set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink "[Out] Headphones"
}

function get_sound_card_index() {
    card_index=$(cat /proc/asound/cards | grep sof-hda-dsp | head -n1 | grep -Eo "^\s*[0-9]+")
    # remove leading white spaces
    card_index="${card_index#"${card_index%%[![:space:]]*}"}"
    echo $card_index
}

sleep 2 # allows audio system to initialise first

card_index=$(get_sound_card_index)
if [ $card_index == "" ]; then
    echo "sof-dha-dsp card is not found in /proc/asound/cards"
    return 1
fi

old_status=0

while true; do
    # if headphone jack isn't plugged:
    if amixer "-c${card_index}" get Headphone | grep -q "off"; then 
        status=1
        move_output_to_speaker
    # if headphone jack is plugged:
    else
        status=2
        move_output_to_headphones
    fi

    if [ ${status} -ne ${old_status} ]; then
        case "${status}" in
            1)
                message="Headphones disconnected"
                switch_to_speaker
                ;;
            2)
                message="Headphones connected"
                switch_to_headphones
                ;;
        esac

        echo "${message}"
        old_status=$status
    fi

    sleep .3
done
```

#### huawei-soundcard-headphones-monitor.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Huawei soundcard headphones monitor

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/huawei-soundcard-headphones-monitor.sh
Restart=always
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```